# How to bulk replace links that are embed to words in Excel cells

Tags: worksheet-function, batch-rename, microsoft-excel-2013, cells, bulk

I have a huge list of words that have links. All the URLs have text that repeats. I want to mass replace this text with another. Right now, "Replace all" only searches between words, not through the embed hyperlinks behind words.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is with a Macro:

```
Public Sub ReplaceHyperlinkURL(FindString As String, ReplaceString As String)
Dim LinkURL, PreStr, PostStr, NewURL As String
Dim FindPos, ReplaceLen, URLLen As Integer
Dim MyDoc As Worksheet
Dim MyCell As Range
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Set MyDoc = ActiveSheet
For Each MyCell In MyDoc.UsedRange
If MyCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
 LinkURL = MyCell(1).Hyperlinks(1).Address
 FindPos = InStr(1, LinkURL, FindString)
 If FindPos > 0 Then 'If FindString is found
  ReplaceLen = Len(FindString)
  URLLen = Len(LinkURL)
  PreStr = Mid(LinkURL, 1, FindPos - 1)
  PostStr = Mid(LinkURL, FindPos + ReplaceLen, URLLen)
  NewURL = PreStr & ReplaceString & PostStr
  MyCell(1).Hyperlinks(1).Address = NewURL 'Change the URL
  End If
 End If
Next MyCell
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
MsgBox ("ReplaceHyperlinkURL error")
End Sub
```

The ReplaceHyperlinkURL code must be placed in a VBA code module. From a spreadsheet, Press Alt+F11 to open the VBA Editor. Then select Insert - Module from the menu. Copy the code and paste it into the module. Then save the module.

In order to run the procedure, create a macro that contains following line and run the macro in Excel. Be sure to replace the FindText with the portion of the address you want to find and ReplaceText with the text you want to replace it with.

> Call ReplaceHyperlinkURL("FindText", "ReplaceText")

[Source](http://cnx.org/content/m17228/latest/)

Comment: I'm in stuck the macro part. I don't know how to create the macro and run it. How can do this?

Comment: @Karolinger [Create or delete a macro - Microsoft Office Support](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010342374.aspx)

Comment: Holy Moses, @Moses. You saved my life! Thank you very much, man!

Comment: @Karolinger Glad I could help :)